# Argument of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the argument $ \theta $ of a complex number z that satisfies the following condition:
$|exp (z^3)| \to 0$ as $|z| \to \infty$

I suspect the real part of $z^3$ must be negative and this is enough to work out the angle, but I can't really justify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need that $\mathrm{Re}\, z^3<0$. But if $z=r\,\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}$, then $z=r^3\,\mathrm{e}^{3i\vartheta}=r^3(\cos3\vartheta+i\sin 3\vartheta)$ and $\mathrm{Re}\, z^3<0$ if and only if
$$
\cos 3\vartheta<0 \quad\text{if and only if}\quad 3\vartheta \in (\pi/2,3\pi/2) \!\!\!\mod 2\pi
$$
which means that
$$
\vartheta \in (\pi/6,\pi/2)  \!\!\!\mod 2\pi,
$$
or
$$
\vartheta \in (5\pi/6,7\pi/6)  \!\!\!\mod 2\pi,
$$
or
$$
\vartheta \in (9\pi/6,11\pi/6)  \!\!\!\mod 2\pi.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Write $z=re^{i\theta}$.  Then
$$|\exp(z^3)|=\exp({\rm Re}(z^3))=\exp(r^3\cos3\theta)\ .$$
If you want this to approach $0$ when $\theta$ is fixed and $r\to\infty$, any $\theta$ such that $\cos3\theta<0$ will do.

Comment: But why $ |exp(z^3)| = exp(Re(z^3))$?

Comment: $\exp(x+iy)=e^xe^{iy}=re^{i\theta}$ where $r=e^x=\exp({\rm Re} (z))$ and $\theta=y={\rm Im}(z)$.  A very useful elementary property of complex numbers.